# setOnCompletionListener is not working

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have an onCompletion Listener for MediaPlayer, but it's not working after the MediaPlayer stops, and it's causing an error. I want to change the button background after the audio stops; here's the code:

```
  btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPlaying == false) {
                isPlaying = true;
                try {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                    btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_play_button);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), path[flag]);
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                isPlaying = false;
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);
            }
        }
    });
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), path[flag]);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You should override the method

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
    @Override        
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);
    }
});
```